# Flexbox children, mix of rows and columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using flexbox to align my 4 elements in a row.

[image]

I then want to break this down for mobile like so:

[image]

I have successfully reordered the elements here:

```css
.flexcontainer {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
}

.flexcontainer>div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #E46119;
  border: 1px solid #626262;
  margin: 3px;
}

.flexcontainer>div:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 0;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  order: 3;
}

.flexcontainer>div:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-flex: 2 0 0;
  flex: 2 0 0;
  order: 2;
}

.flexcontainer>div:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-flex: 2 0 0;
  flex: 2 0 0;
  order: 1;
}

.flexcontainer>div:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 0;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  order: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
  <div>four</div>
</div>
```

But I am stuck on how to break down child elements "two" and "three" into their own rows. And then how to make element "one" and "four" each 50% wide on their own row.

Is what I'm trying to do possible without additional HTML markup? Thanks for your advice.

```css
.flexcontainer {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
}

.flexcontainer>div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #E46119;
  border: 1px solid #626262;
  margin: 3px;
}

.flexcontainer>div:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 0;
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

.flexcontainer>div:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-flex: 2 0 0;
  flex: 2 0 0;
}

.flexcontainer>div:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-flex: 2 0 0;
  flex: 2 0 0;
}

.flexcontainer>div:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 0;
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
  <div>four</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The desktop-mobile transition can be achieved with CSS only using flexbox.

No changes are necessary in the HTML.

```css
.flexcontainer {
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
}

.flexcontainer > div {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #E46119;
  border: 1px solid #626262;
  margin: 3px;
}

.flexcontainer > div:nth-of-type(1) { flex: 1 0 0; }
.flexcontainer > div:nth-of-type(2) { flex: 2 0 0; }
.flexcontainer > div:nth-of-type(3) { flex: 2 0 0; }
.flexcontainer > div:nth-of-type(4) { flex: 1 0 0; }

@media screen and ( max-width: 500px) {
  .flexcontainer { flex-wrap: wrap; }
  .flexcontainer > div:nth-of-type(1) { order: 3; flex-basis: 34%;  }
  .flexcontainer > div:nth-of-type(2) { order: 2; flex-basis: 70%; }
  .flexcontainer > div:nth-of-type(3) { order: 1; flex-basis: 70%; }
  .flexcontainer > div:nth-of-type(4) { order: 4; flex-basis: 34%;  }

}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
  <div>four</div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zw10dzzn/23/)

***How it works***

- The media query kicks in when the screen is 500px or less.
- The [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property sets the order of items on the screen. The default value is 0 for all items.
- With [`flex-wrap: wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) on the container, flex items can now wrap.
- With [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) set to a positive integer, there's no need for [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) to be precise. Since `flex-grow` will consume free space on the row, `flex-basis` only needs to be large enough to force a wrap.
- If a  precise `flex-basis` value is preferred, any borders, padding and margins would need to be factored in, maybe using `box-sizing: border-box` and/or `calc` ([example](https://jsfiddle.net/zw10dzzn/5/)).

Comment: Thanks so much my flexbox skills are making gains. Can you advice on a support for IE, on a windows machine? 
How come it works on chrome for mac but not pc?

Comment: You're welcome. Check for *prefix requirements* and *browser support* here: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: Excuse me, I meant to say IE. I am looking into prefix solutions now. Will post my findings.

Comment: It seems that it was the "calc" within the flex.
see this article.
https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#8-flex-basis-doesnt-support-calc

Answer (score 3):

You could group "three" and "two" into their own flex box and use `flex-wrap` to achieve this.

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zw10dzzn/3/

You may have to play around with the margins and the order to get exactly the layout you want.

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: red;
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* allow elements to wrap in mobile view */
}

.flex-container .one, 
.flex-container .two-and-three, 
.flex-container .four {
    background-color: magenta;
}

.flex-container .one, 
.flex-container .four {
    height: 100px;
    margin: 3px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-basis: auto;
}

.flex-container .two-and-three {
    order: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-container .two-and-three .two, 
.flex-container .two-and-three .three {
    background-color: #FC0;
    flex: 1 0 100%;
    margin: 3px;
    height: 100px;
}

.flex-container .two-and-three .two {
    order: 2;
}

.flex-container .two-and-three .three {
    order: 1;
}

.flex-container .one {
    order: 3;
}

.flex-container .four {
    order: 4;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    
    .flex-container {
        flex-wrap: nowrap; /* back to single row */
    }
    
    .flex-container .two-and-three {
        flex-grow: 4;
        flex-basis: auto; /* stop spanning the whole row */
        flex-wrap: nowrap; /* back to single row */
    }
    
    .flex-container .two-and-three .two,
    .flex-container .two-and-three .three {
        flex-basis: 50%;
    }
    
    .flex-container .two-and-three .two {
        order: 1;
    }

    .flex-container .two-and-three .three {
        order: 2;
    }
    
    .flex-container .one {
        order: 1;
    }
    
    .flex-container .four {
        order: 4;
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="one">one</div>
    <div class="two-and-three">
        <div class="two">two</div>
        <div class="three">three</div>
    </div>
    <div class="four">four</div>
</div>
```